# Forbid characters in Ubuntu password

Tags: ubuntu, security, password, pam

How can I forbid an user to set a password with e.g. the german Umlaut characters `äöüÄÜÖß` on a Ubuntu 22.04 ?
Even the non-Ubuntu [pam regex module](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/pam-modules/manual/html_chapter/regex.html) can only regex on usernames and not on passwords.

Comment: You probably need to use pam_script to call on a custom script to deny setting passwords that contain “forbidden” characters. AFAIK that is not something that you can enforce with the conventional Pam modules such as pam_pwquality

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by @HBruijn you can use the [pam-script module](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/pam-script.7.html).

Example `/etc/pam.d/common-password`

```
  # here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
  password   requisite pam_pwquality.so minclass=2 minlen=3 usercheck=0 dictcheck=0 gecoscheck=0 maxclassrepeat=0 maxsequence=0 maxrepeat=0 enforce_for_root
  # forbid german umlauts
  password   requisite                      pam_script.so
  password   [success=1 default=ignore]   pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass yescrypt
  # here's the fallback if no module succeeds
  password   requisite pam_deny.so
  # prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
  # this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
  # since the modules above will each just jump around
  password   required pam_permit.so
  # and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
  # end of pam-auth-update config
```

The script in `/usr/share/libpam-script/pam_script_passwd` looks like

```
  #!/usr/bin/bash
  
  if [[ "$PAM_AUTHTOK" != *@(ä|Ä|Ä|ä|Ö|ö|Ü|ü|ß)* ]]; then
    exit 0
  else
    >&2 echo "Error. Invalid Password. Password must not include German Umlaut (e.g. ä, Ö, ß)"
    exit 1
  fi
```

Make sure the script is executable and readable by u,g,o and not writeable by others. E.g. u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx

Comment: Just a caution - in the age of Unicode and in general creating a list of “forbidden” characters for passwords is probably neither  going to ensure “stronger” passwords nor will it ensure 100% portable passwords. A list of “allowed” characters might work better in that regard.